# Issue joining tables: wrong results returned

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have sql statement like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`porudzbina_item`.`porudzbinaid`) AS `cnt`, `robaid`
FROM `porudzbina_item`
WHERE `porudzbinaid` IN (SELECT `porudzbinaid` FROM `porudzbina_item` WHERE `robaid` = @RID)
GROUP BY `robaid`
ORDER BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

which select me top 5 `ROBAID` inside table `PORUDZBINA_ITEM` with most repeats.

Now `ROBAID` comes from table `ROBA` which have other data inside like `REL`. `REL` is not stored inside `PORUDZBINA_ITEM`, only `ROBAID` so what i need to do is join two tables `ROBA` and `PORUDZBINA_ITEM` and get `ROBA.REL` based on repeats of `PORUDZBINA_ITEM.ROBAID` inside table `PORUDZBINA_ITEM`.

What i have tried is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`porudzbina_item`.`porudzbinaid`) AS `cnt`, `roba`.`rel`
FROM `porudzbina_item` 
    LEFT JOIN `roba` ON `roba`.`robaid` = `porudzbina_item`.`robaid`
WHERE `porudzbina_item`.`porudzbinaid` IN 
        (SELECT `porudzbinaid` 
        FROM `porudzbina_item` 
        WHERE `robaid` = @RID)
GROUP BY `rel`
ORDER BY `cnt` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

but it returns me nothing.

What have i done wrong?

Here is some data:

Table `PORUDZBINA_ITEM`

```
porudzbina_item_id     |     porudzbinaid    |    robaid    
        1              |           1         |      34      
        2              |           1         |      26      
        3              |           2         |     105      
        4              |           2         |      14      
        5              |           3         |      26      
        6              |           3         |      11     
        7              |           3         |      26     
        8              |           3         |      22      
        9              |           3         |      34
```

Table `ROBA`

```
ROBAID    |    NAZIV          |    REL
  34      |    Grejp          |    grejp
  26      |    glass          |    glass
  105     |    OrangeGlass    |    orange-glass
  14      |    phone          |    phone
  11      |    iphone         |    iphone
  22      |    pc             |    pc
```

First code (which works) when returned it gives me 5 items like this:

```
3, 26 // Robaid shows 3 times in this table
2, 34 // robaid shows 2 times in this table
1, 105 // robaid shows once in this table
1, 14 // robaid shows once in this table
1, 11 // robaid shows once in this table
```

but now what i need besides count of how many times it is inside table ordered descending is corresponding `REL` for that `ROBAID` which is pulled from another table `ROBA` so expected result with second query would be:

```
3, 26, glass
2, 34, grejp
1, 105, orange-glass
1, 14, phone
1, 11, iphone
```

Important: in first query i am using `where robaid = @myParameter` and that `robaid` is part of main table, but now i need to use `where rel = @myParameter` and `rel` is column in second table.

As you can see in expected result i do have 3 columns but when i have `rel` i do not need `id` but i implemented it here in example for easier understanding.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: If you could provide some sample data it will help us to validate our answers!

Comment: I have updated my question. Please let me know if there is anything else

Answer (score 0):

1st query:

```
select count(*) cnt, robaid from porudzbina_item group by robaid order by cnt desc;
```

output:

```
+-----+--------+
| cnt | robaid |
+-----+--------+
|   3 |     26 |
|   2 |     34 |
|   1 |    105 |
|   1 |     14 |
|   1 |     11 |
|   1 |     22 |
+-----+--------+
```

2nd query:

```
select count(*) cnt, p.robaid, r.rel
from porudzbina_item p
left join roba r on p.robaid = r.robaid
group by p.robaid order by cnt desc;
```

output:

```
+-----+--------+--------------+
| cnt | robaid | rel          |
+-----+--------+--------------+
|   3 |     26 | glass        |
|   2 |     34 | grejp        |
|   1 |     11 | iphone       |
|   1 |     22 | pc           |
|   1 |    105 | orange-glass |
|   1 |     14 | phone        |
+-----+--------+--------------+
```

Just join and group it. There is no need to use subqueries, parameters etc.